# docker webpack-dev-server: not found

Tags: docker

I want to create a container for client with vue.js. I already have my project: I copied it to a `client` folder and added a `Dockerfile`.  The "client" container created successfully, but I am getting an error

> webpack-dev-server: not found

and my `node_modules` folder is empty.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:6.14.0-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
apk add --no-cache bash git openssh
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/client

WORKDIR /usr/src/client
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD npm start
```

This is `docker-compose.yml`

```
client:
    # Use a static website hosting service in production
    # See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/client
    build:
      context: ./client
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/client
    command: npm start
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/client:rw,cached
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
```

Comment: The `volumes:` line basically hides everything the `Dockerfile` does and replaces it with what's on the host (including the `node_modules` directory).  If you have a MacOS or Windows host and a Linux container, or if you have an Alpine-based container (which you do), that can lead to "exec format error" or "command not found" type errors.